# How to structure Rails project by features instead of controllers, models and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder if anyone tried to structure their Rails project something like

- users

  - users.rb
  - users_controller.rb
  - users_index.html.erb
  - users_show.html.erb
- posts

  - posts.rb
  - posts_controller.rb
  - posts_index.html.erb
  - posts_show.html.erb

instead of the Rails default where you put stuff into *models*, *views* and *controllers* folders? Could you share some insights on how to modify load paths and how this works with Sprockets or code reload in development or even generators? I just recently started using AngularJS and I really like how you organize things by feature there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of the Rails principles is **Convention Over Configuration** so if you do it like you want you will lose a lot of cool things rails offers. Imagine someone trying to maintain your app, he will get crazy trying to figure it out what you did.

Honestly, if you want to play with rails, try to do it following its principles, just give it a try ;)

Comment: I "play" with Rails since 2008 ;)

Comment: I was just asking the question out of curiosity. You are probably right about maintenance though. :)

Comment: @schneikai, I thought you're a starter, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you have been playing with Rails since 2008 then you should full well know that this is not something you should do in Rails. Rails is an opinionated MVC framework. The moment you deviate its conventions you will feel the pain and the ride will get very rough. Imagine things like partial lookups, routes, load paths, authorization, authentication, etc...

With that said, it's easy to build an architecture that uses micro service objects. This gives you the best of both worlds. You can think of those service objects as "features". This is only worth it in complex apps. I am building one at the moment and I've had great results breaking up functionality into small services, or "features" if you will, interacted with by controllers. It makes testing easy, isolates logic in the right areas, and does wonders for reusability.

For example, a feature would be updating a document.

```
class UpdateDocument
  attr_reader :user, :document

  def initialize(user, document)
    @user = user
    @document = document
  end

  def call(params)
    document.update! params.merge(last_editor: user)
    UpdateDocumentJob.perform_later(document)
  end
end
```

And the controller would be:

```
  def update
    UpdateDocument.new(current_user, @document).call permitted_attributes(@document)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, success: t('.success') }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a way to hack your way around the Rails conventions but the question shouldn't be if it is possible. I think you should ask yourself what the benefit of such a folder structure would be for you and then look for the appropriate alternative in the Rails world. I think however that changing the folder structure is not a good idea as this is one of the core design decisions of Rails.

Instead - let's say you like that structure because you want to be able to switch between model/view/controller of a specific feature very quickly I would recommend you try to get used to some workflow like fuzzy search to open files in Atom or even write an extension for your text editor of choice. That keeps your repo clean and still speeds up your workflow.